# React Redux - props in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create an app and a part of my app is something like a Counter game. I've got a whole component but I need to use the value of a prop from this component in another component, and a function that will increase value in another component. How should I do it?

```
    class ClickCounter extends Component {   static mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
          count: state.count
        };   };   static mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return bindActionCreators(
          {
            increaseCount,
            decreaseCount
          },
          dispatch
        );   };
         render() {
        const { increaseCount, decreaseCount } = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
          <button onClick={increaseCount}>+</button>
          <span>{this.props.count}</span>
          <button onClick={decreaseCount}>-</button>
          </div>
        );
}
}
 export default connect(
  ClickCounter.mapStateToProps,
  ClickCounter.mapDispatchToProps 
 )(ClickCounter);
```

Comment: Work with same store/state and connect the store  to second component.

Comment: Please format your code. The indentation is inconsistent which makes it difficult to read.